# Evitar script de confirmación al abrir links externos

Tags: javascript, html

Amigos, tengo el siguiente script de confirmación de cierre:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit(){
        return "¿Quieres salir de esta página?";
    }
</script>
```

Pero en mi html tengo algunos href para imprimir PDF que se abren en una página externa(es decir, mi página actual no se cierra), **mi duda es cómo puedo hacer que este script solo se ejecute cuando le doy en la "X" al navegador y no cuando le doy clic a los enlaces.**

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cómo se abren los PDF para imprimirlos? ¿En una nueva pestaña o con el menú de impresión? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de un enlace?

Comment: Así es, se abre en una pestaña nueva para imprimirlos o descargarlos así <a href="report/reportePDF.php" target="_blank" alt="PDF" title="Descargar/Imprimir PDF" style="display:inline"></a>

Comment: No consigo reproducir el problema. Cuando hago click en ese enlace, se abre una nueva pestaña y yo no veo el mensaje de "¿Quieres salir de esta página?" (que sí veo cuando le doy a la X de cerrar pestaña/ventana)

Comment: No, eso es lo que quiero lograr, que cuando de click en ese enlace no me muestre el mensaje ¿Quieres salir de esta página?, es decir, que solo me lo muestre cuando realmente voy a salir de mi página dando clic en X de cerrar

Comment: Esa es la cosa. A mí no me sale ese mensaje cuando hago click en el enlace.

Comment: ¿Puedes crear un [mcve] para que veamos el problema? (comparte el código mínimo con el que te da el mensaje incluso pulsando en el enlace). También, ¿en qué navegador estás probando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es crear **una función** para controlar cuando salgas por hacer click y poder distinguir cuando sea por cerrar el tab del navegador.
Luego agregas **una variable de control**.
Tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
    var Clicked = false;
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    
    function confirmExit(){
        if (!Clicked) {
            return "¿Quieres salir de esta página?";
        }
        
    }
    function DescargarPDF (url) {
     Clicked = true;
     var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
        win.focus();
        Clicked = false;
    }
</script>
```

```html
<a onclick="DescargarPDF('report/reportePDF.php')" alt="PDF" title="`Descargar/Imprimir PDF" style="display:inline">Wherever</a>
```

Comment: Lo he probado y me fue perfecto, muchas gracias